# Integrating BOT with ASP.Net Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, botframework

I have built a BOT using Microsoft BOT Framework which works fine, I have tested from BOT Emulator, now I want to integrate it with ASP.Net Application. I tried to figure out how to do it from Web Application but I couldnt find out any tutorials to understand how to pass parameters. Can you give me some tutorials which explains this.

Comment: I voted to close because this q is both too broad and requesting 3rd party learning resources. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic#help-post-body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire [`BOT Framework SDK`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder) is open-source and up on github. There are plenty of examples of how to do this in the [CSharp/Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore) or [Node/examples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs) directories. It is as simple as any other **Web API** call that you'd make, where it's an **HttpPost** with the body being the object that the server is capable of deserializing.

Comment: the links to the examples are not valid any more.

Comment: @Snympithey are now... thanks