# How to integrate a chat bot in a web site both being developed on MS .net

Tags: bots, botframework

I have developed a chat bot using Microsoft BOT framework.
Now I want to integrate this BOT in my web site which is developed in asp.net.
Please provide me some links or tutorial or steps how can I achieve the same.

Thanks in advance,
Subrat

Comment: Please provide the research you have done so far. At what point doesn't it work for you anymore. What is your exact issue. Asking for tutorials is not what this site is for ;-).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integrating BOT with ASP.Net Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37114384/integrating-bot-with-asp-net-application)

Comment: Refer this: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat

Answer (score 0):

> Now I want to integrate this BOT in my web site which is developed in asp.net.

It seems that you’d like to embed your bot to your ASP.NET website, the [Web Chat channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-channel-connect-webchat) provides the ability for users to interact with a bot directly in a web page, you can use the supplied  code to easily embed your bot into your websites.

```
<iframe src='https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/{your_botid}?s=YOUR_SECRET_HERE'></iframe>
```

Besides, you can add [DirectLine channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/bot-service-channel-connect-directline) and include botchat.js in your website application to integrate your bot in your website, and which enable us to pass user specific information to bot from website app, like this.

```
<script>
    BotChat.App({
        directLine: { secret: '{your_directline_secret}' },
        //you can dynamically retrieve the logged in user info in your website app
        //and pass thoes info to your bot
        user: { id: '1234', firstname: '{your_fname}', lastname: '{your_lname}'},
        bot: { id: '{your_botid}' },
        resize: 'detect'
    }, document.getElementById("mybot"))
</script>
```

**Note**: this blog:[Customize Web Chat for your websites](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/11/customize-web-chat-websites/) is for your reference.

Comment: Thank you every one for the response. I tried searching for the question but some how could not get a proper response.Thus asked for tutorial. I'll follow on the above link.And if I need any help I'll start a separate link for specific question.

Comment: Hi @SubratKP, any updates? are you able to embed your bot to your ASP.NET website now? If the reply is helpful, you can mark it as accepted answer, which can help others quickly find this thread and solve similar issue.